# How to initialize module-level variables in Python with a method?

Tags: python, scope

In Java, if I wanted "an unchanging variable that is available to all methods in a class without being passed as an argument", I would do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final OtherClass OTHER_CLASS = buildOtherClass()

  ...

  private static OtherClass buildOtherClass() {
    //<creation logic>
  }

}
```

However, if I try to do something similar in a Python script, I get an error:

```
$ cat python_test.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

DICTIONARY = buildDictionary()

def methodThatUsesDictionary()
  ...

def buildDictionary():
  d = {}
  for i in range(5):
    d[str(i)] = i
  return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
  methodThatUsesDictionary()

$ ./python_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    DICTIONARY = buildDictionary()
NameError: name 'buildDictionary' is not defined
```

If I move the variable declaration below the method declaration, the code runs as expected. It feels really unintuitive to me, though, for code legality to depend on element ordering, - the method *exists* in the file, I don't understand why it can't be found just because it "hasn't been declared *yet*". Moverover, putting general (non-method-specific) variables up at the top of a file is a code convention that I find really sensible and helpful - "here's an overview of the things we're going to be working with" (though I guess that's less true in Python, where you don't have type declarations to give additional context).

I can see a couple of ways that I could get around this, none of which are aesthetically pleasing:

- As detailed above, I could declare the method before the variable.
- I could put the constructor method in a subsidiary module, and import that into the script - I dislike this because it seems excessive to extract logic which may only be a few lines long.
- I could put this script's logic inside a Python class, and initialize the variable in the `__init__` method. Again, this seems like unnecessary overhead.
- Set the variable as a global variable from a method that's called from the `__main__` method, as in the code below. I've seen a lot of guidance suggesting that global variables are a danger sign, though, so I suspect I should avoid this, too.

(I need to put text here otherwise the snippet below is unformatted, presumably because of the bullet immediately above)

```
$ cat python_test_2.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def initializeGlobalVariables():
  global DICTIONARY
  DICTIONARY = {}
  for i in range(5):
    DICTIONARY[str(i)] = i

def doOtherLogic():
  for key in DICTIONARY:
    print('DICTIONARY[' + str(key) + '] is ' + str(DICTIONARY[key]))

def main():
  initializeGlobalVariables()
  doOtherLogic()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
$ ./python_test_2.py
DICTIONARY[0] is 0
DICTIONARY[1] is 1
DICTIONARY[2] is 2
DICTIONARY[3] is 3
DICTIONARY[4] is 4
```

It may be that what I'm trying to do is completely unpythonic, and so the lack of support is "by design". I'd love to get some feedback on style and structure from more experienced Python users.

Comment: Putting "constants" at (or near, just before the main stanza) the end of the file is not anti-Pythonic, and you should get comfortable with doing so even if it goes against your sensibilities.

Comment: What Ignacio said...  Also, please go look [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Can you give some advice on which section of pep8 I'm violating? I'm aware of it, but it's a helluva large document to look through to find the point you're referring to. Is it to do with naming conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and Java are fundamentally very different languages, with Python being much more like a scripting language than compiled (even though it does get compiled on-the-fly). Also, Python doesn't really have quite the concept of "an unchanging variable...", at least not by variable name. Variable names are essentially pointers to any type of data (see: dynamic typing) and without some special python decorators you can always change the value of a variable, sometimes quite to your detriment.

More to your point though, because of its scripting nature (and that it can be executed interactively), the order of things matters:

```
>>> def test():
...     print x
... 
>>> test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
>>> x = 1
>>> test()
1
>>>
```

In this case, the global `x` in the function `test` is just a pointer and it doesn't matter that `x` doesn't exist yet because you haven't tried to run `test`. This might seem counter-intuitive when coming from a strongly-typed and compiled language, but it allows for a lot of nice things like dynamic imports that will only load modules as the functions are used:

```
>>> def dyn_import():
...     import random
...     for i in xrange(5):
...             print random.random()
... 
>>> random.random()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
>>> dyn_import()
0.246957404578
0.302236192705
0.614960539467
0.0928052533036
0.389804554563
>>> random.random()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'random' is not defined
```

If every variable needed to be fully defined before being used inside a function, then defining `dyn_import` would fail unless `random` was loaded and it was understood what `random.random()` means. In this case, it is not loaded until the function is actually executed. Additionally, since the function does not put the module into the global namespace of the script, the module is discarded as soon as the function is finished.

It's just one example of how this can be very beneficial, although a pretty important one.

Comment: That's a great explanation of where my intuitions were incorrect - thank you! So what would be a more pythonic way to do what I'm trying to do (initializing a variable when a script starts that is available to all methods in that script)? Sounds like it should be my final snippet (creating a method that sets a global variable, and calling that before the actual script logic)?

Comment: Yes, at the end of your script is where it should go, if it's an instance of a class you have defined in your script. However if you import from another module and then need an instance of something to use in your script, it typically goes at the top. Often what programmers will do if they are making a script to run by itself is to put all the functionality into a `main()` function and then call it at the very end. This gets around many of the annoyances of how things are defined in order.